# Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a Guid c# aspx

Tags: c#, asp.net, guid

I'm trying to get the current GUID for the current page and saving the value into SQL. When the page loads it loads the GUID in a label. So I want to take the GUID from the label and put in into sql but it gives me the error: Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a Guid. This is my code:

```
   protected void btnAddOGCoverageTeamMembers_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            string AccountGUID = base.Request["account"]; 
            guidget.Text = AccountGUID.ToString();

            Hashtable htAMTeam = new Hashtable();
            htAMTeam["GUID"] = guidget.Text; 
            htAMTeam["UserID"] = Convert.ToInt32(Person.SelectedValue);
            htAMTeam["Location"] = Location.SelectedValue;
            htAMTeam["Product"] = Product.Text;
            obj.addTeam(htAMTeam);

        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            lblMsg.Text = ex.Message;
        }

    }
```

This is the code behind page: .cs page

```
public void addTeam(Hashtable htAMTeam)
{
    SqlParameter[] OGTeamparam = new SqlParameter[4];
    OGTeamparam[0] = new SqlParameter("@AccountGUID", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier);
    OGTeamparam[1] = new SqlParameter("@UserID", SqlDbType.Int);
    OGTeamparam[2] = new SqlParameter("@Location", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
    OGTeamparam[3] = new SqlParameter("@Product", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);


    OGTeamparam[0].Value = htAMTeam["AccountGUID"];
    OGTeamparam[1].Value = htAMTeam["UserID"].ToString();
    OGTeamparam[2].Value = htAMTeam["Location"].ToString();
    OGTeamparam[3].Value = htAMTeam["Product"].ToString();
    SqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(OGconnection, CommandType.StoredProcedure, "InsertAccountOGTeam", OGTeamparam);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've gotten it to work, This did the trick:

```
   OGTeamparam[0].Value = new Guid(Convert.ToString(htAMTeam["AccountGUID"]));
```

Comment: I did (green star)

Answer (score 4):

Instead

```
OGTeamparam[0].Value = htAMTeam["AccountGUID"];
```

use

```
OGTeamparam[0].Value = new Guid((string)htAMTeam["AccountGUID"]);
```

Comment: I got this error:  CS0246: The type or namespace name 'GUID' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @ParbhuBissessar my bad, I missspelled GUID. Use Guid. I edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks and sorry I got another error: The best overloaded method match for 'System.Guid.Guid(byte[])' has some invalid arguments

Comment: Try `Guid.Parse(htAMTeam["AccountGUID"])` ?

Comment: @ParbhuBissessar Should works, htAMTeam["AccountGUID"] is a string? [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/96ff78dc(v=vs.110).aspx) is an Guid example.

Comment: when i tried that I get 'System.Guid' does not contain a definition for 'Parse' @fharreau

Comment: @BWA yes it's a string. The GUID was converted to a string and now I need to convert the string back into a guid

Comment: @ParbhuBissessar: According to your own answer, you did store into `htAMTeam["AccountGUID"]` a `string`, but when you get it back, you get an `Object` (because the indexor returns an object, not matter what you store in it). That's why `new Guid([..])` did not work.